# SenCha Touch able to to full screen and can't exit the application or not?

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Since we are using Eclipse to develop Android, we have found that the limitation.
because of some user are using Window, Android or IOS. different Operating system we have to develop different applicaiton ,
why not using SenCha touch, only develop 1 time, then we can use on any Operating System.
But i have some question don't know whether Sencha Touch Able to do the following function or not

### Question

1)Sencha Touch able to let application full screen and hide the android status bar, the device to use only able to execute the application we have created, can't open any others application or browser. can or cannot?

2)Sencha touch able to do like a application? not a web site?

3)and user can't exit the application. able to do this function, Yes or No?

4)when Android start up application run the sencha application we have create.once the application execute, user can't execute anything like what i have mentioned on Question #1 and #2.

*Please Answer the Question #1 #2 #3 #4 with clearly answer Yes or No*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kevhendar has mentioned above, you can of course create a native app using Sencha Touch. Here are my understanding below:

Question #1:

**YES**, Sencha Touch does allow you to create apps that run like native applications (full screen apps as you say) on your mobile devices. One of the powerful features is that you can develop native applications (though technically 'native' refers to app that are created using core technologies) as well as mobile web apps. So, the answer to your question is YES, you can hide the status bar by building your app with native packaging tool (link mentioned by Kevhender).

Question #2:

**YES**, you can create app-like apps using Sencha Touch. A part of answer can be found from above.

http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/

Question #3:

My understanding is that you do not want the user to exit the application just by tapping the exit button or close button just like we do on a website. If that's the case, the answer is **YES**. When you create a native app using Sencha Touch, you obviously do not have the option for an user to have a close button or something like that.

Question #4:

This is not clear. However, if you want to run your application on startup. you need make some permission in your manifest file (Which I think it has nothing to do with Sencha Touch).

I hope this helps you by some manner.

Comment: 1 more question, Sencha Native application able to run in Window Operating System or not?because it is java language

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your question, you are looking to make a native app with Sencha Touch, which can indeed be done.  This can be done entirely with just the Sencha Touch framework, or you can use PhoneGap to assist and allow for additional native device functionality.

Sencha Touch native build guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/native_packaging
PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/

Using either of these, a Sencha Touch native app will (question 1) run fullscreen and hide the Android status bar.  Questions 3 and 4 don't really make sense to me, but hopefully the guide above will assist you as needed.

Comment: @Kechender 1 more question, Sencha Native or PhoneGap's application able to run in Window Operating System or not?because it is java language

Comment: Absolutely, yes it can be run in Windows.  See the full list of platforms here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support

Comment: how about Sencha Touch Native Applicaiton? also able to run i Window Operating System?

Comment: Yes, the link in my original post shows the platforms that ST Native can build for, Windows included.

Comment: i mean in Window 7/8 not Window Phone...is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sencha Touch is a mobile application framework, not meant for desktop apps.

Comment: Sencha did have something called Desktop Packager that allowed an ExtJS app to be turned into a native desktop app, but that product was recently discontinued.  https://www.sencha.com/products/sdp

Comment: because the customer have 2 different operating system devices, 1 on running Window 8 Operating system, another one is Android, so i hope that we develop for 1 time, do no need to develop twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40017/discussion-between-chin-ye-and-kevhender)